# SQL developer won't show tables in the connections Tab

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Why do tables, views etc. not show up under the databases? (please refer to the screenshot).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Because you're in the **DBA Navigator** view. See that tiny "DBA" above the green plus sign? Normally, it says "Connections", but - now you're in DBA mode so - it displays options appropriate for DBAs.

That can be switched in the "View" menu. Select

- Connections, or
- DBA